# why is this an invalid directory?

Tags: java, android-studio

> ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211
> Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
> location of your Java installation.
> Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I had set the direction in the System Properties, but it didn't help

Comment: 1. Does that directory exist? 2. Does it have a valid installation of Java in it (With the bin directory and all) 3. Does the version of Java (1.8) match the version of your source and compilation of your project. You might be using Post 9 (Modular) Java in your project but referencing a 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add path for HOME directory of JDK Folder

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\Contents\Home
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem the solution i dowloaded Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable from here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/247854802#comment12